# Spring Security Handler - Access denied vs Page not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, error-handling, spring-security, aop

I would like to use two different pages for error handling in spring security.

In case the user does not have permission to access a web page I redirect him to an access denied page using the following

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="permitAll" /> 
<security:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />
```

However, if an user mistype an url (404 page not found) I want the user redirected to error.jsp page. At the moment this is redirected automatically by spring to the access denied page.
How can I distinguish the two in Spring security

This my Error Handler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler
{
    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public String handleAccessException(AccessDeniedException ex)
    {
        return "denied";
    }

    // This is my attempt
    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    public String handleAnyException(Throwable ex)
    {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Spring Security kicks in before it even reaches the servlet. It matches on URL sees you aren't allowed and locks you out, as it should. IMHO you shouldn't make a difference here because when you make a difference you are leaking a little of your structure and security to the outside...

Comment: @M.Deinum I was wondering about that. So are you suggesting this is a bad practise ?

Comment: Well it would be strange if a user goes to `/foo/bar` and gets a 404 whilst `/foo/baz` yields a security exception... Whilst `/foo/**` would be the protected URL. This could trigger a malicious user because he now knows that `/foo/baz` is a valid URL to test for hacking...

Comment: Oh Yeah, I agree. I should not implement that, therefore. Now, jush being curios, is it actually possible to do that

Comment: Well no not with a pattern like `/foo/**` as that would match everything. It would only be possible if you have a fine grained mapping for all of your URLs in your app.

Comment: I am fine with these tips. If you post your answer I will accept it. Thanks a lot.